# Como puedo dar un formato de ***** a mi campo de CLAVE en mysql

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
SELECT
usuario.idUsuario AS CODIGO,
CONCAT(funcionario.Nombre,' ',funcionario.Apellido) AS FUNCIONARIO,
usuario.Alias AS ALIAS,
/**/
usuario.Clave AS CLAVE,/*El resultado debe de mostrase con un formato*/
/**/
IF(usuario.Activo = 0, 'Si','No') AS ACTIVO
FROM usuario
INNER JOIN funcionario ON usuario.idFuncionario = funcionario.idFuncionario
```

Comment: Me resulta muy raro eso que quieres hacer. Estas seguro de que eso es lo que quieres hacer?? Quiero decir, ¿no te estarás refiriendo a que lo que quieres hacer es codificar el campo clave en la tabla de usuarios? Date cuenta de que si es eso lo que quieres, la columna de clave va a estar siempre llena de asteriscos de longitud, el tamaño de la clave, pero no vas a guardar una información "util" en ese sentido. De hecho, perderás la clave. Si me estoy equivocando, te pido disculpas.

Comment: De qué sirve seleccionar la clave y ver solo asteriscos? La idea de seleccionar los datos es mostrarlos y hacer uso de los mismos, pero si quieres mostrar asteriscos cuál sería el objetivo de eso? si no se va a visualizar sería mejor ni siquiera seleccionarlo en la consulta. Parece que hay un error en el uso que le vas a dar a la clave. Tal vez estés confundiendo ese trabajo con lo que se visualizaria del lado del cliente, pero si es así hay mejores formas de hacerlo. Sería bueno que nos expliques en que situación vas a necesitar que cumpla ese caso. Asi podemos darte una solución más óptima.

Comment: Hola @VíctorHugoTirado, a veces hay situaciones en las que es necesario realizar un proceso de `masking` a los datos que devuelven las consultas. No entraré en detalles de las posibles implementaciones. Pero te puedo sugerir que leas [MASKING-MariaDB MaxScale 2.1.](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-22-masking/). Hay muchos casos de uso para realizar el `masking` de datos personales. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Una solución que puedo darte es que pruebes lo siguiente, si sabes el tamaño del campo `usuario.Clave`.

Supongamos que el campo tiene 5 caracteres.

```js
SELECT usuario.idUsuario AS CODIGO,
  CONCAT(funcionario.Nombre,' ',funcionario.Apellido) AS FUNCIONARIO,
  usuario.Alias AS ALIAS,
  /**/
  /* El resultado se mostrará con 5 '*' */
  INSERT(usuario.Clave,1,'*****') AS CLAVE,
  /**/
  IF(usuario.Activo = 0, 'Si','No') AS ACTIVO
FROM usuario
INNER JOIN funcionario ON usuario.idFuncionario = funcionario.idFuncionario
```

Es lo que se me ocurre que puedes hacer en este caso.

Puedes leer la documentación de [INSERT Function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/insert-function/).

Saludos.